# Module can not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, can-bus

I'm having trouble setting up my CAN environment and using ICSim.

I'm new to Linux. This is the first thing I've ever tried.

I set up my WSL following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment#set-up-your-linux-username-and-password).

I am primarily following [this article](https://medium.com/@yogeshojha/car-hacking-101-practical-guide-to-exploiting-can-bus-using-instrument-cluster-simulator-part-i-cd88d3eb4a53)  to set up the CAN interface. Everything looks good up until the "Preparing the Virtual CAN Network" step. When I try to do ./setup_vcan.sh , I get "modprobe: FATAL: Module vcan not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2".

I've bounced around to a couple different guides but the problem is consistent. I don't see anyone manually adding the can or vcan modules to the directory so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or how I can add those.

./setup_vcan.sh

returns

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module can not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
modprobe: FATAL: Module vcan not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Error: Unknown device type.
Cannot find device "vcan0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/740322/18571 but copying my answer here:

I was trying to do a Yocto build that worked fine on Ubuntu 22.04 native but failed on WSL2 because it couldn't find `/lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`:
[murata-wireless/cyw-fmac - Build fails on WSL2](https://github.com/murata-wireless/cyw-fmac/issues/4)

I eventually found this [workaround](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/zeus-build-under-WSL/m-p/1054109):

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic
ll /lib/modules
# Note the directory that has been installed here, e.g. `5.15.0-67-generic/
# Use "uname -r" or note the directory the build above failed to find, e.g. `/lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`
sudo ln -s /lib/modules/5.15.0-67-generic /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Update: Updates to WSL2 can break this as the directory name can change, e.g. 5.15.0-67-generic/ upgrades to 5.15.0-69-generic/. I created a script to automate this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

WSL2_VERSION=$(uname -r)
echo "WSL2_VERSION = $WSL2_VERSION"

WSL2_LINK="/lib/modules/$WSL2_VERSION"
if [ -L "${WSL2_LINK}" ]; then
    if [ -e "${WSL2_LINK}" ]; then
        echo "Good link"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Broken link"
        rm "${WSL2_LINK}"
    fi
elif [ -e "${WSL2_LINK}" ]; then
    echo "Not a link"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Missing"
fi

shopt -s nullglob
for filename in /lib/modules/*; do
    echo "$filename"
    if [ -z "$HEADERS_DIR" ]; then
        HEADERS_DIR="$filename"
    else
        echo "HEADERS_DIR already set to $HEADERS_DIR, fail"
        exit 1
    fi
done

if [ -n "$HEADERS_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Create symbolic link $WSL2_LINK => $HEADERS_DIR"
    ln -s "$HEADERS_DIR" "$WSL2_LINK"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get back into WSL. It's currently hanging at boot and I'm trying to solve that..

Comment: Done both and even the scripts print 'Good link', but the error still is in my FACE!